# Integration Tests with Microservices (NodeJS), Jenkins and Docker

Tags: node.js, git, jenkins, docker, microservices

How would you typically configure Jenkins to build microservices (multiple NodeJS services, Rabbit, Mongo, etc), then test those services all together ?

Let's say I've the following services:

- RabbitMQ
- Mongo
- NodeJS Service 1
- NodeJS Service 2

Each of them has their own tests (unit and integration) and their Dockerfile.

I want to configure Jenkins in a way that it would enable me to clone all theses services, run them all at the same time in different containers with Rabbit and Mongo containers along them. It would then run the tests for each of those services (they do generate TAP and coverage reports). Then take those reports for the TAP/Coverage Jenkins plugins. If it works out, commit the image and push it to the docker registry.

I've been lying around Stack and Google and I don't really see an easy way to get there that would not imply tons of bash.

Maybe I see it in the wrong way, any input is more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can test using an "consumer driven contract" approach.
Like mentioned here:
https://medium.com/@sagansystems/integration-testing-our-microservices-for-fun-and-profit-b749ef42703b#.q7dyxgfrn
using this project:
https://github.com/realestate-com-au/pact

Comment: Well thanks for your answer and the reference but that doesn't really answer my initial question. I did give a try with bash and at the moment it still seems the best option. My question was more related to how to configure Jenkins..